# jquery mobile header repeat across pages

Tags: php, jquery, mobile, jquery-mobile, footer

I'm setting up a multi-page jquery mobile page based on the provided template: 
http://jquerymobile.com/demos/1.1.1/docs/pages/multipage-template.html

How can I get the header/footer to repeat on all the pages without duplicating it in the page content.

Is there a jquery script for this or do I have to use some kind of php include file?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 3):

You can use JS (jQuery) to make a template and append it to each `data-role="page"` element as it's being created.

```
//create template, notice the "{TITLE}" place-holder for dynamically adding titles
var myHeaderHTML = '<div data-role="header" data-id="my-header" data-position="fixed"><h1>{TITLE}</h1></div>';

//create delegated event handler for the "pagecreate" event for all pseudo-pages
$(document).on('pagecreate', '[data-role="page"]', function () {

    //get the title of this page, if none is given then use a generic title
    var title = $(this).data('title') || 'Some Generic Title';

    //add the header to this pseudo-page
    $(this).append(myHeaderHTML.replace('{TITLE}', title));
});​
```

Here is a demo: http://jsfiddle.net/vmMVj/

This will append a fixed header to every page as it is being created. I added support for passing a unique title by adding a `data-title="Some Title"` attribute to the `data-role="page"` element.

Note that I chose the `pagecreate` event because it occurs when the pseudo-page is about to be initialized. If you were to bind to the `pageinit` event, you'd be too late and have to initialize the header widget manually.

Comment: In my header I have a Select Menu for a Choose Language component. Like the OP I do not want to have multiple instances of this component, and so this idea seems good. But apparently when I move __<div data-roll='header'>__ from page to page (using .append(...) as suggested here), the functionality of the Select Menu breaks ...

Comment: Apparently, you have to use the `pagebeforecreate` event if you want to add data attributes, as per the docs: http://api.jquerymobile.com/pagebeforecreate/ However, I've tried both approaches without luck :(

Comment: When I say I haven't had any luck, I mean: I can't get my custom event handling functions to execute when jQuery Mobile fires the specified events. Putting an `alert("test")`or `console.log("test")` statement in the above function has no effect. I've tried placing the above function various places in my code but to no avail.

Comment: @JoeDyndale It sounds like your event handler is created at the wrong time or in the wrong place.

Comment: Yeah, that's what I figured as well, but I've tried setting it up globally, in the mobileinit event handler, in $(document).ready(), in the deviceready handler and a couple of other places I can't think of right now. None of these places worked. All of these places are after all the necessary libraries and application-specific js files are loaded. So I'm running out of places to try.

Comment: @JoeDyndale `pagecreate` is specifically for external HTML documents. If you are linking to pages that are all in the same HTML document then try `pageshow` or one of the other jQuery Mobile page-events.

Comment: All my pages are external HTML files.

Answer (score 2):

As far as I know, you must include a header and footer within each `data-role="page"` container. If you wan't to avoid typing this out for each page, then I would `require_once()` a page in PHP that includes the header or footer, and use that in place of writing out a header and footer each time.

**Sample:**

```
<section data-role="page">
<?php require_once("header.php"); ?>

<div data-role="content">
<p>Hello world!</p>
</div>

<?php require_once("footer.php");?>
</section>
```

**header.php:**

```
<header data-role="header">
<h1>Title</h1>
</header>
```

**footer.php:**

```
<footer data-role="footer">
<<p>Footer content here</p>
</footer>
```

Answer (score 0):

Why more JS ?? ... instead of adding two elements for header and footer (either "header" and "footer" tags, or divs with appropriate classes, but mandatory with "position: fixed;") - and add padding top and bottom of the pages divs ? ... No JS code  needed ... which will improves the performance ... although very little :) ...

Comment: Different solutions will certainly work for different situations. This solution is good for JS performance however `position:fixed` is a resource-intensive property to set (which will slow down redraws). Both of those performance differences are most likely quite small.