# jQuery mobile: Why does Select Menu break when I append it to another DOM node on a different page?

Tags: jquery, dom, jquery-mobile, select-menu

I have a jquery mobile site with three pages (`<div data-role = 'page'>`).

On page 1's header I have a Select Menu  being used for a Choose Language component:

`<div data-role = 'header'> ... <label></><select><options></></> ... </>`.

I *do not* want multiple instances of the language chooser component throughout the site.

So, following a suggestion from [SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12009398/jquery-mobile-header-repeat-across-pages) I am moving the header-node from page to page upon each page's pageshow event.

When I go to page 2 the Select Menu dis-functions; but when I navigate back to page 1 it works again.

Comment: What do you mean by "dis-functions"?

Comment: it seems to be receiving the mouseclick (in the address bar a '&ui-state=dialog' get appended to the URL and it highlights on mouseover, etc), but it does not open the menu.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using "pagebeforeshow" not "pagecreate" event, because pagecreate will be called just one time at creation of that page.

so, if you want to get a event every time to change a page, you should use 'pagebeforeshow', 'pagebeforehide.'pageshow' or 'pagehide'.

and i recommend **pagebeforeshow** for changing UI before page showing. :)

---

Did you use .remove() API for moving 'select' from previous to new page? .remove() removes a element from parent and its data & event also. so, you should re-define event handler after removing.

Additionally, .detach() for just detach element from its parent. but it has some issues about jquery mobile's enhancing.

i post a jsfiddle about above. [jsfiddle.net/cwdoh/ZaVch](http://jsfiddle.net/cwdoh/ZaVch)

***EDIT BY SHANNON** ... in case the fiddle gets removed in the future, here is your code:*

```
    <div data-role="page" id="page1">
        <div data-role="header">
            <h1>Page 1</h1>
            <select id="language-select">
                <option>Korean</option>
                <option>English</option>
                <option>JavaScript :)</option>
            </select>
        </div>

        <div data-role="content">
            <a data-role="button" href="#page2">go to Page2</a>
        </div>
    </div>

    <div data-role="page" id="page2">
        <div data-role="header">
            <h1>Page 2</h1>
        </div>

        <div data-role="content">
            <a data-role="button" href="#page1">go to Page1</a>
        </div>
    </div>

$(document).on( "pagebeforeshow", function( e, data ) {
    // move language-select from previous page
    var selectMenu = data.prevPage.find( "#language-select" );

    selectMenu
        .remove()     // remove from previous page
        .appendTo( $(e.target)   // append to active page
            .find( "[data-role='header']" ) );

    // bind event handler after append
    $("#language-select").bind( "change", function() {
        alert( "language-select changed" );
    });

    // re-build 
    selectMenu.selectmenu();
});
```

Comment: cwdoh, thanks for responding ... yes I am currently using 'pageshow'. And it is successfully firing as I navigate through the pages. But the Select Menu does not work when I'm on pages other than page 1 (which is where the Select menu was upon site load).

Comment: oh, i understand. so you're using 'language-select-menu' from single definition in every page but your handler function of select-menu works only page 1. right?

Comment: I want to mention that I had to add **jQuery( e.target ).find('[class=\"ui-select\"]').remove();** AFTER your select-menu move step. I was getting duplicate Select Menus (your fiddle is not having this problem). So for me order of actions is: **1 -** move <select> structure to new DOM location, **2 -** __remove any existing jqm wrapper stuff from any previous visit to this page__, **3 -** set event listener, **4 -** call selectmenu() method.

Comment: if you want to remove enhanced DOM from your document, call 'destroy' for the element like .selectmenu( "destroy" ); don't remove it.

Comment: this does not mention the 'destroy' option: http://jquerymobile.com/demos/1.2.0/docs/forms/selects/methods.html ... it seems to be for UI widgets

Comment: in my opinion, jquery mobile widget use same as jquery UI's widget factory (ref. : https://github.com/jquery/jquery-mobile/wiki/Creating-jQuery-Mobile-Plugins ). so, if you want to use it, that's ok.